# Long description in tooltips

Tags: usability, gui-design, tooltips

I'm working on a project that has tooltips for some buttons. These tooltips contains very lengthy description and those are client requirements that cannot be changed. 
These tooltips take a considerable amount of space when popping up which is not very pleasing. What are the alternative methods that I can take to achieve this ?

Comment: Alternative method in what way? You said this is a client requirement that can't be changed... so, there you go. If the client is truly seeking UX perhaps it would be best to change their minds, as tooltips are not designed to serve as online help.

Comment: @EvilCloset The description of tooltips cannot be changed...

Comment: Are u sure it is a tooltip that you need and not a help option that could open the so-called tooltip the client wants? I can provide a quick mock-up if you consider the option.

Comment: @AleodorTabarcea It is a tooltip that client wants.

Comment: It is generally a bad practice to show so much information in a tooltip but we might find a solution. Could you give us a little more information on the project, a screen maybe, if it is web or desktop solution. Something to give us more context?

Comment: @AleodorTabarcea Didn't start the development phase yet and this is a web solution. This is more like a dashboard used by employees in the company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed that showing full text is not eye pleasing, but client wants that functionality. You can may be strike a balance using below approach..

[image]

User can choose to see more of the message by clicking on the see more link. After that you can either do a pop up or expansion of tool tip or floating pane to show full text , as it fits your needs.

Comment: how would one click on the 'show more' button if the label moves with the mouse?

Comment: technically I'm sure this can be accomplished.. quick search showed me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231315/jquery-ui-tooltip-html-with-links

Comment: I was thinking the same... Thanx

Comment: Client is happy with this.